# Valid characters for Domino fullname

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Usually when adding a web user to the address book of my Domino server I create a Person document and set a unique fullname (field "FullName") in canonical format (for example "*CN=John Smith 8/O=Organization*"). However, in order to not have to worry about uniqueness and to easily derive a user's mail address directly from his/her fullname, I would like to generate a fullname based on the user's mail address. Here is an example:

> Mail address: **john_smith.001@my.web-users.com**
>
> Derived fullname: **CN=john_smith.001/O=my.web-users.com**

Unfortunately, I have not found a documentation on what charaters are valid  / safe to be used in fullnames, but I would like to know

**(A) if all characters that can be used in mail addresses (except for "@", "=" and "/") can also be used in fullnames and**

(B) if there could be problems with document access in NotesDocuments whose authors and readers fields contain fullnames with "special" characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notes canonical names follow the X400 standard (only difference is to use a slash instead of a semicolon to separate the parts - allowed in 3.2.1 of the spec). X400 uses [RFC1685](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1685) for the format. The spec doesn't say anything about characters other than / = and @, so you can use `.`.
You should (the Notes specs says it somewhere) never use `.` in a Domain name for a Notes domain (spaces are also a bad idea).

I had the practice to name the common name of my servers after their DNS names: server1.acme.com/OU=ServersNorth/O=Acme - saved me the headache to create connection documents (but freezes Domain names).

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer.